# Take string value from appsetting.json and set it to JSON Key in c#

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am taking the key from appsetting.json into c# code. Now I have to capture that and get the value from JSON Response in foreach loop c#

In appsetting.Json:
`"CustomField": "customfield_10118"`

and code where i have to capture the value:

[image]

Comment: what exactly do you mean from this *"and get the value from JSON Response in foreach loop c#"* i see no json response in your code? also don't paste images of code

Comment: @MichaelRandall, I apologise for pasting images of code. Actually. I have consumed the CustomField from appsetting.json which is having the value customfield_10118. Now when looping it k.fields.customfield_10118 is having the value "ABC". Now I want to get the "ABC" into epicKey.

Comment: @Vishvjitshinde What is the data type of k.fields? and what is the error you are getting on that line? Please paste the code that depicts the structure of combined.

Comment: Don't apologize for pasting images of code -- don't do it. Replace it with your code as text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe You are in need of [indexer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/indexers/)?

As I cannot assume anything about `k` but it consists of fields `id` and `fields` (both unknown type) and as You are trying to use a `string` variable as a key You would either need the `fields` to be of type [`IDictionary<string, ...>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.idictionary-2?view=netframework-4.8) or You can provide an indexer for the class of `fields`.

1) Dictionary:

```
k.fields = new Dictionary<string, string>();

...
string CustomField = ...;
epicKey = k.fields[CustomField]
```

2) Indexer

Let assume that `fields` inside `k` is a type of `SomeClass`. Then inside `SomeClass`:

```
public class SomeClass
{
  ...
  public string this[string key] {
    get {
      return ...
    }
    set {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

assuming that You are storing all those values somewhere else and indexer is only a way to get them from it, to make this syntax proper:

```
string CustomField = ...;
epicKey = k.fields[CustomField]
```

To summarise:

- if `fields` is already well defined class and You just need to add a support of indexing or handle some custom logic of setting or getting values: use indexer,
- in any other case - use dictionary.